# How can I fetch the ALAsset of the ALAssetsGroup posterImage?

Tags: ios, objective-c, alassetslibrary

I am looking for a way to find the `ALAsset` of a given `ALAssetsGroup` that corresponds to its `posterImage`.

The `posterImage` property of the group only returns a `CGImage`, and I'd like to get the `ALAsset` that the image matches. Is this possible `enumerateAssetsWithOptions` over the group, I can't find any properties that would match or indicate which assets is the poster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no such way. But `posterImage` is usually the most recent asset in the `ALAssetsGroup` (Not true for `ALAssetsGroupAlbum`, always true for `ALAssetsGroupSavedPhotos`). And the documentation says about the order of the assets in a group:

*"An ALAssetsGroup object represents an ordered set of the assets managed by the Photos application. The order of the elements is the same as the user sees in the Photos application. An asset can belong to multiple assets groups"*.

With this assumption, you can achieve the `posterImage` as an `ALAsset` something like this:

```
ALAssetsGroup * group;
[group enumerateAssetsWithOptions:NSEnumerationReverse usingBlock:^(ALAsset *alAsset, NSUInteger index, BOOL *innerStop)
{
    if (alAsset) // first non-nil element will be the recent asset
    {
        * innerStop = YES;

        // do something with the alAsset
    }
}];
```

Comment: makes sense - what about when the user sets the key photo for an album/face. i guess this is the only case where we can't find the poster asset. all other times would be the last photo, yeah?

Comment: You can test it for other `ALAssetsGroupType`s. I had not seen it except albums.